# How to read POST data in sveltekit

Tags: javascript, next.js, svelte, sveltekit

Hi I am beginner in sveltekit. I try to get post data in sveltekit here is my POST Request.

I am using axios to send post data.

```js
const request = await axios
      .post("/api/user", {
        username,
        email,
        password,
        repassword
      })
      .then((e) => {
        console.log(e)
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
      });
```

and this is my POST Endpoint:

```js
// src/routes/user/+server.ts
export const POST = async({request}) => {
    console.log(request)
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({something: 1}))
}
```

this api working fine with GET methods.

Comment: (Please see [formatting documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), code blocks require multiple backticks.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the routes just don't match.
`src/routes/user/+server.ts` equates to just `/user`.